# Dockerfile - Multiple processes - How to introspect GraphQL schema?

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

Is there a way to do the following in a Dockerfile?

In process 1 (`/api`):

- install dependencies
- compile
- start a server (long running process)

In process 2 (`/client`):

- install different dependencies
- run a script that sends an HTTP request to an endpoint that the previous process should be listening on
- compile

Then, move the compiled assets from `/client` to `/api`?

For concreteness, the use case is that we have a GraphQL server and a client, and the client needs to introspect the GraphQL schema in order to compile.

Comment: You would have to do it all in a single `RUN` line: Docker images never contain running processes, and anything left running at the end of a `RUN` line is terminated.  You might find it less fragile to check in the JSON result of the introspection query to your client's source tree.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Do any, perhaps more idiomatic, ways of guaranteeing that a GraphQL schema is always up to date before generating a release come to mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we we're using Elixir / Absinthe, this command worked for us.

```
mix absinthe.schema.json
```

This generates the GraphQL schema without needing to run the GraphQL server.

https://hexdocs.pm/absinthe/Mix.Tasks.Absinthe.Schema.Json.html